# Capture the values of checkboxes in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

consider that there is a checkbox named abc,if we check that checkbox,it display a message "abc is checked",simillarly if multiple checkboxes are checked,then a message should display along with all the names of the checkboxes seperated by commas,like "abc,dbc is checked".how to get it?

Comment: `abc.Checked`. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: You can try `if abc.Checked = True`

Comment: @Aishvarya... not like this. It is `if(abc.Checked == true)`.

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, WPF?...are all the CheckBoxes in the same container?  Does the order matter?